# .NET 4.0 DataAnnotations GAC/EntityFramework conflict

Tags: asp.net, .net, entity-framework-6, gac

I'm trying to build an ASP.NET web site for Microsoft .NET 4.0 using Entity Framework 6. The website is explicitly targetting .NET 4.0 in `web.config`:

`<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">`

, IIS Express' application pool in `applicationhost.config` also targets .NET 4.0:

`<add name="Clr4ClassicAppPool" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" managedPipelineMode="Classic" CLRConfigFile="%IIS_USER_HOME%\config\aspnet.config" autoStart="true" />`

When the site is launched, a number of `CS0433` compiler errors is shown, ones like below:

`error CS0433: The type "System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.TableAttribute" exists in both "c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll" and "c:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\e798ee36\2b3f5a24\assembly\dl3\fd34a92a\0052703a_0990d101\EntityFramework.DLL"`

As far as I remember, there should be no `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` assembly in .NET 4.0, or at the very least it shouldn't contain classes like `TableAttribute`, `KeyAttribute` etc. The only lead I have is the bottom line of error page, which says

```
Microsoft .NET Framework, version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET, version:4.6.1055.0
```

however, I don't know how to change specifically ASP.NET version for a website (of course, if that's the problem's source).

Comment: Have you tried to: 1) Right click the solution in VS, then select `Clean Solution`, 2) Right click the solution and then select `Rebuild Solution`. No guarantees here, but it might help since one of the DLL:s mentioned in the error is in the `Temporary ASP.NET Files` folder.

Comment: @user1429080 Yeah, that was the first thing I've tried.

Comment: So you sure that there are no references to System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations assembly anywhere in your Visual Studio project?

Comment: do you have more than one context having same table name in your project?if so than change the table name.

Comment: @AlekseiOmelaienko did you get anywhere with this? I am having the same problem right now! Cheers

Comment: @EvalKeneval Sadly, no, had to abstain from using EF back then.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the compilation batch to false?

```
<compilation debug="false" batch="false">
```

Comment: Haven't tried it as it seemed to do nothing as per [description](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s10awwz0%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Tried it now - sadly, to no visible effect.

Comment: *seemed to do nothing with my problem

Comment: you can also try creating new App Pool with managePipeLineMode = Integrated.

Comment: Even though I fail to see what does pipeline mode have to do with that particular case, I'd try it, but that's impossible due to production being needed to work in WS2003/IIS6 environment, which has no integrated pipeline mode support.

Comment: I checked our servers and saw that all. Net4.0  app pool using were configured as integrated...but you are right iis6 dont have that option.

Comment: Well anyway, I still fail to grasp what has app pool's pipeline mode to do with there being `TableAttribute` or `KeyAttribute` in `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` assembly in .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you've got code in your App_Code folder (likely your Entity Framework classes at the least?).

Now you could move your code out of there, and precompile everything so that you deploy the website assembly and not any source files.

Otherwise, you really need to look at your projects and ensure that nothing is referencing System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.

Also, check any web.config in the project at the root, or in the App_Code folder(s) and make sure there is no

```
<add assembly="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
```

under system.web/compilation/assemblies. If there isn't, you could even try putting in

```
<remove assembly="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
```

e.g.:

```
<compilation>
    <assemblies>
        <remove assembly="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

You can also check to make sure it's running the earlier version of ASP.NET so that it picks up the version of the DataAnnotations assembly that doesn't have the Schema attribute (as the 4.5+ framework version does):

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: David, sorry for ignoring your answer in due time. It, however, is sadly irrelevant to my problem. Perhaps it wasn't completely clear from question, but the problem is that there shouldn't be any conflict at all, as `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` in .NET 4.0 should contain no DB schema annotation attributes at all, but somehow the conflict still arises. And yes, there's no such problem with a precompiled version of my website, the problem is that I can't use a precompiled one.

Comment: Hi. I've updated my answer for syntax highlighting, but have you tried specifying the targetFramework on the httpRuntime config? i.e. <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.0" />

Answer (score -1):

Hey Can you check your project.Please check there should not be two model with same properties.Model can also be entity framework class model

Answer (score -1):

Check if all NuGet packages for your project are updated or if there are any installed that you don't want.